# Generate random number on demand for each element in an infinite list

Tags: haskell

I would like to generate a list of random numbers (0, 1) for each element in a stream of integers. I was trying to build a comprehension list this:

```
randomNums = [(i, r) | i <- [1..], r <- SR.newStdGen]
```

I simply cannot figure out how to do this. Can anyone help? The output I'm looking for is the original element, i and an associated random float. For example:

```
[(1, 0.20381), (2, 0.1128373), ...
```

Comment: Is the stream of integers the normal counting ones (like 1, 2, 3, etc) or could it be any sequence of integers?

Comment: They could really be anything and in any order. Strings, Ints, etc. I want to create a random float for each item in this list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `zip` to pair them up:

```
Prelude System.Random> let g = mkStdGen 42

Prelude System.Random> take 10 . zip [1..] . randomRs (0.0,1.0) $ g
[(1,0.11040701265689151),(2,0.8453984927258916),(3,0.30778213446209723),(4,0.781
3880826070412),(5,0.5242581917029475),(6,0.5196911001158159),(7,0.20084688456283
112),(8,0.47947729750989876),(9,0.3240164101179728),(10,6.1566369505963836e-2)]
```

As you can see, these are not really random; with the same initial argument (here, 42), the same sequence will be produced:

```
import System.Random

randomNums :: [a] -> Int -> [(a, Float)]
randomNums list initVal = zip list . randomRs (0.0,1.0) . mkStdGen $ initVal
```

If you're using this function from inside `main`, you can also randomize the `initVal` value itself,

```
main = do 
  ....
  initVal <- randomIO :: IO Int
  .... -- use initVal ....
```

Comment: How can this be used in a main function? The code works inside GHCi, but I get errors when I try to run inside of main as `print $ randomNums [1..10] 3`

Comment: @turtle I've changed type signature. Try now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `newStdGen` is `IO StdGen`, so you can't use it in pure functions at all, only in the `IO` monad. You could make your function return `IO [(Int,Double)]`, but that's not really nice, it would pull everything into `IO`. I'd recommend using the [`Rand` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.9/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html#t%3aRand) instead:

```
randomNums :: RandomGen g => Rand g [(Int,Double)]
randomNums = do
    randDoubles <- getRandoms
    return $ zip [1..] randDoubles
```

or simply

```
randomNums = fmap (zip [1..]) getRandoms
```

Note that `Rand` is little more than a reader monad (aka function) for random generators, so you can easily rewrite it without the `MonadRandom` package:

```
randomNums :: RandomGen g => g -> [(Int,Double)]
randomNums = zip [1..] . randoms
```

only, that signuature will be less pleasant to use if you have multiple things that need random generators; the `Rand` monad automatically takes care for distributing them. With the explicit function you'll keep on having to call `split` all the time, this quickly gets messy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This looks very clear; however, I get errors. What is `randoms`? `zip [1..] . randoms` I also get errors with `randomNums = fmap (zip [1..]) getRandoms`. What is `getRandoms`?

Comment: [`randoms :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [a]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=randoms) is from the base package, you have that already (apparently imported `qualified  System.Random as SR`, so it's `SR.randoms` for you). [`getRandoms :: (Random a, MonadRandom m) => m [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.9/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html) is from MonadRandom, you may need to `cabal install` that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure list of randoms then use WillNess's approach.  If you want an impure list, then use the `pipes` library to lazily stream an impure list:

```
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.State
import System.Random

randomNums :: (Proxy p) => () -> Producer p (Int, Double) IO r
randomNums () = evalStateP 0 $ forever $ do
    i <- get
    r <- lift $ randomRIO (0, 1)
    respond (i, r)
    put $! i + 1
```

You read out the list by supplying the appropriate transformation and consumption stages.  For example, if you want to take the first 10 elements and print them, you write:

```
>>> runProxy $ randomNums >-> takeB_ 10 >-> printD
(0,0.2204881851502879)
(1,0.2507730220341101)
(2,0.8870240857313229)
(3,0.5556581036216822)
(4,0.6564558289397481)
(5,0.7499290459359478)
(6,0.10963804170328961)
(7,9.475221797586297e-2)
(8,9.342816284834865e-2)
(9,0.23343178814756815)
```

`pipes` gives you a way to work with effectful lazy lists without sacrificing the ability to manipulate them using high-level transformations.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, that's supposed to be a ghci prompt.  It's just a habit I got from writing haddocks.

Comment: That's very nice, but unless you're already using `pipes` for IO reasons I'd rather dispute it's worth to use them here. Ordinary lazy lists are completely fine for infinite random streams.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's right.  That's why I qualified this with the initial statement that it's only worth it if you want them purely for the sake of using the impure versions of the random functions.